# Graphics issue when Assigning Expressions

Tags: graphics, education

I was under the impression MMA directly substituted everything when assigned. Obviously I'm missing something subtle with either how substitution works in a notebook or how the `Disk` function takes an expression. (I guess the 3rd option might be that it's some sort of graphical bug in the WebGL performance of MMA online.) Do I need to change the `Head` of the "d" expression? How do I do that?
This is a simplified version of a Neat Example for `Disk` in Wolfram doc center. In any case, I'd really like to learn about what's going on here.

```
Graphics[Table[Disk[RandomReal[4,{2}],RandomReal[1]],40]]
```

[image]

```
Clear[d];
d:={RandomReal[4,{2}],RandomReal[1]}
Graphics[Table[Disk[d],40]]
```

[image]

Comment: It is a {} issue. You have many of them. Try this `Graphics[Table[Disk[Sequence@@d],40]]` and see if it works for you.

Comment: Yes that fixed it. Did you want to answer this? `Sequence`:"represents a sequence of arguments to be spliced automatically into any function."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the result of `d` as sequence resolves the extra {} issue.

From help

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So this should now work

```
Clear[d];
d:={RandomReal[4,{2}],RandomReal[1]}
Graphics[Table[Disk[Sequence@@d],40]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Boom. The internet works! Problem solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives.

```
SeedRandom[42]
d := {RandomReal[4, {2}], RandomReal[1]}
Graphics[Table[Disk @@ d, 40]]

SeedRandom[42]
d := Sequence[RandomReal[4, {2}], RandomReal[1]]
Graphics[Table[Disk @ d, 40]]
```

Both produce

[image: blobs]